# How to center container on resize using onWindowResize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a script that is resizing my .container when my window is resized. This is my page: http://cjehost.com/qt/nipt/page6.php

If you resize the browser window, you'll see the container resize but not stay centered. Is there a way to center my container? Here is my script:

```js
  // Resize the map to fit within the boundaries provided

 function resize(maxWidth, maxHeight) {
   var image = $('img'),
     imgWidth = image.width(),
     imgHeight = image.height(),
     newWidth = 0,
     newHeight = 0;

   if (imgWidth / maxWidth > imgHeight / maxHeight) {
     newWidth = maxWidth;
   } else {
     newHeight = maxHeight;
   }
   image.mapster('resize', newWidth, newHeight, resizeTime);
 }

  // Track window resizing events, but only actually call the map resize when the
  // window isn't being resized any more

 function onWindowResize() {

   var curWidth = $(window).width(),
     curHeight = $(window).height(),
     checking = false;
   if (checking) {
     return;
   }
   checking = true;
   window.setTimeout(function() {
     var newWidth = $(window).width(),
       newHeight = $(window).height();
     if (newWidth === curWidth &&
       newHeight === curHeight) {
       resize(newWidth, newHeight);
     }
     checking = false;
   }, resizeDelay);
 }

 $(window).bind('resize', onWindowResize);
```

My css:

```
 .container {margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: `$(window).resize(onWindowResize);`

Comment: just saw this and added it - thanks. My container is responsive on this page but not staying centered - especially as you get down to the smaller breakpoints. There is a 15px left pad and the right butts up against the window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend really a CSS approach instead of JavaScript approach for this one. Responsive CSS with `@media` queries are there for this. Don't use DOM Manipulations with JavaScripts, that are really costly in the terms of performance.

**CSS Centering**

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**`@media` Queries**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  // Styles for Mobiles
}
@media screen and (min-width: 381px) and (max-width: 760px) {
  // Styles for Tablets
}
@media screen and (min-width: 761px) {
  // Styles for Desktops
}
```

You can find an exhaustive list online.

Comment: I'm already running bootstrap which normally resizes the image but since there is a conflict between bootstrap and another jquery script I'm running (imagemapster), I'm using the above script (function resize(maxWidth, maxHeight)...) to make the image responsive. If I were to load the page without the imagemapster code, the image would be responsive. Right now the container div is already centered, my image is responsive, but it's not centered in the container div.

Comment: @phillystyle123 Ah I get it.

Comment: Correction: it's not just the image. It's the entire window that is now resizing, but not staying centered within the browser window. As the browser window size gets smaller, the container shifts over to the right and there is a horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work by replacing window with .container (my container div). It's still a bit clunky - i.e. when I switch to full screen from smaller resolutions the container doesn't always resize. Here is my working code:

```js
// Track window resizing events, but only actually call the map resize when the
// window isn't being resized any more

function onWindowResize() {

  var curWidth = $('.container').width(),
    curHeight = $('.container').height(),
    checking = false;
  if (checking) {
    return;
  }
  checking = true;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var newWidth = $('.container').width(),
      newHeight = $('.container').height();
    if (newWidth === curWidth &&
      newHeight === curHeight) {
      resize(newWidth, newHeight);
    }
    checking = false;
  }, resizeDelay);
}



$(window).bind('resize', onWindowResize);
$(window).resize(onWindowResize);


});
```

Here is a working fiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jQG48/1007/)

I found reference to this approach and fiddle here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689621/responsive-image-map-resizes-larger-than-100-of-container)

Thanks to [@LBF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274595/lbf)